# how do i clear my frame screen in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a brick game. I want the screen to get clear after every 0.1 second so that i can redraw every thing on the frame screen.

Is there any way to directly clear the frame screen without any event occurence??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
```

and do all your drawing in there.

Then you start a timer, which calls

```
repaint();
```

Here is a basic example:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    int x = -1;
    int inc;

    public MainFrame() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MainFrame.this.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // don't call super.paint(g), we do all the painting

        if(x > getWidth()) inc = -5;
        if(x < 0) inc = 5;

        x += inc;

        // here we clear everything
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(x, 0, getWidth()-x, getHeight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        mainFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did its not working here.
I mean the new rectangle is getting over written on the previous one.
resulting in a complete mess. I want my paint mehthod to first clear all the previous drawings and then redraw it..

Its not happening here...

Comment: I don't see how this could happen. Have you tried to run a copy of my example without changing anything to see if that works? Maybe you could post the relevant parts of your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen every X milliseconds, you can use a [javax.swing.Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) which takes an ActionListener. As for the actual clearing action, the first thing that comes to mind is [Graphics.clearRect()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#clearRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) but I suspect there may be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Do what Peter suggested but [override paintComponent instead of paint](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/#swing).

I also suspect that you will find that this will flicker pretty badly (redrawing the whole screen constantly).  You might want to find a better way to do that... unfortunately that isn't an area I know too much about.  [Here is a simple bouncing ball demo that might help](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-create-a-bouncing-ball-animation.html).

Comment: Excellent link to the sun earticle! I would override paintComponent if I would like to have the border painted by Swing. Since that's not what I wanted I used paint to increase performance. The flickering you refer to can be avoided by double-buffering (described in the sun article).