# How to refresh Jframe to create ainimation?

Tags: java

I have a simple animation program which moves some basic shapes on the Jframe. However, the program does not really move the shapes, but creates more instead. In other words, I need to force the Jframe to clean up the previous object. How to do so?

Comment: By shapes, do you mean swing Components? Or do you just pain on your JFrame?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957011/how-do-i-clear-my-frame-screen-in-java/1957117#1957117).

Answer (score 0):

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of a JPanel. The basic code is:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g); // this is what clears the screen.
    // paint your shapes here
}
```

Then you add the panel to the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on "Custom Painting" for more information.